# Link2sd boot issues

Tags: storage, insufficient-memory, link2sd

I've got a stock, rooted firmware on my LG Optimus One (P500) handset.
I installed Link2SD, and I've got roughly 100 apps installed.

Whenever I boot my device, however, it takes 5-6 minutes to boot to lockscreen, and then, for ten-fifteen minutes after that, it gives me the "Internal Storage full" error, and a negligible amount of free memory.

Then, Link2SD finally seems to kick in, and I get my 90Mb of free memory.

What's happening? May I solve this issue?

Comment: May I know what Android version (2.2 or 2.3) and what firmware version you have (like v20a, v20c etc)? Mine is 2.3.3 running v20c.

Comment: 2.3.3 running v20g

Answer (score 2):

It's the data stores for the apps that are actually to blame. While you have so many apps installed, all the data they create when you use them is still being stored internally (For speed) and Link2SD has to fiddle with things every time you boot up, which uses internal memory. The best fix for such a low end phone, and I'm speaking from experience, is to create an "apps" directory on the ext partition of your SD card, and use Titanium Backup's batch option. If an "apps" directory exists on the partition, Titanium Backup will recognize the partition and list it as a2sd and give you the batch option to move data to the sd card. Once you're done with this you will see nearly every bit of internal memory on your phone is now free, and your apps can continue to access their data with no errors.

Comment: Wow -- I didn't know about that feature, and I'm using TB for years already! Just googled it and found the corresponding [Howto](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726014) -- but that speaks of a separate partition (not just a folder). Maybe that "extra partition" is rather optional; are you using it without such? Even the [TB FAQ](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-technical-faq.html#requirements-for-using-move-app-data-to-sd) writes the extra partition is required.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest a painful solution - when LG provided update to v20d for my country, I felt the ROM was utter slow and I had to downgrade to v20c. Same could be your situation. But before that:

- try unchecking `Relink lib files at boot` and `Relink dex files at boot` options in Link2SD
- if the above doesn't work try `Clean up the 2nd partition` option.
- Remove link for system apps and move it to internal memory.
- As a last resort, I would try partitioning my sd card and installing back apps in steps to see whether the number of application is the cause of the delay.

Comment: I tried a couple of minuts ago the first and second tip.
They din't work at all. Actually, after rebooting with the relink lib files at boot some apps (Samsung Mobile Printers, Google Maps) left the lib files in the internal.

As for system apps, you mean the updates for the gapps?

As for partitioning, I tried that some time ago.

Comment: In my opinion the internal memory is faster than the external SD card. Hence if frequently used apps and its data are kept in sd card, it should be slow than if it is kept in internal memory - that's my theory. Hence if you keep more apps that require frequent thrashing it should be slow.